# How send and receive string among activity an service in Android

Tags: android, service, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

In my application I use a service that connects to specified device and receives some data in the form of strings.

When it gets some special strings it throws a notification to the user.

When the user clicks on the notification it takes him to a new activity, where the values received from the bluetooth are displayed. What I want to do is to update the textView with the values received from the bluetooth.

I have looked up the net and I found out that my best shot is BroadcastReceiver. I have this handler in onCreate which handles the messages received from the Bluetooth. What i want to do is when I receive a new string to pass it to my Activity:

```
 mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == 1) {
                    connectStat = true;
                }else if(msg.what == MESSAGE_RECEIVE){
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj; 
                    String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                     sb.append(strIncom); 
                     int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("/");
                     if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {
                         String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);
                         Intent in = new Intent();
                         in.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
                         in.putExtra(AlarmService.CO_CONSENTRATION_NUMBER, sbprint);
                         sendBroadcast(in);
                         if(sbprint.equals("4")){
                             NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                             notificationManager.cancel(9999);
                             Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.gasmask, "New Message", System.currentTimeMillis());
                             notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
                             Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(AlarmService.this, ActivityCOConsentration.class);
                             String value = sbprint;
                             notificationIntent.putExtra(AlarmService.CO_CONSENTRATION_NUMBER, value);
                             notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                             PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AlarmService.this, 0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                             notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                             notification.setLatestEventInfo(AlarmService.this, "Alarming CO level", "Level of CO is alarming. Take action.", pendingIntent);
                             notificationManager.notify(9999, notification);
                             myclip.start();
                             sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                         }else if(sbprint.equals("8")){
                             NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                             notificationManager.cancel(9999);
                             Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.gasmask, "New Message", System.currentTimeMillis());
                             notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
                             Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(AlarmService.this, ActivityCOConsentration.class);
                             String value = "8";
                             notificationIntent.putExtra(AlarmService.CO_CONSENTRATION_NUMBER, value);
                             notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                             PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AlarmService.this, 0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                             notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                             notification.setLatestEventInfo(AlarmService.this, "Alarming CO level", "Level of CO is life endagering. Sending out SOS sms.", pendingIntent);
                             notificationManager.notify(9999, notification);
                             myclip.start();
                             disconnect();
                             try {
                                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                             sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                         }            
                     }
                }
            }
        };
```

Here is my activity that is supposed to receive the data:

```
public class ActivityCOConsentration extends Activity{
private TextView co_concentration;
private MyReceiver mMyReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_coconsentration);
    co_concentration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.co_number);
    onNewIntent(getIntent());
    mMyReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    registerIntents();

}

public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String covalue = extras.getString(AlarmService.CO_CONSENTRATION_NUMBER);
    co_concentration.setText(covalue);
    if(covalue.equals("8")){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);
        stopService(i);
    }
}
private void registerIntents(){
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(AlarmService.BROADCAST_ACTION);
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mMyReceiver, filter);
}

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(AlarmService.BROADCAST_ACTION)) {

                String v = intent.getExtras().getString(AlarmService.CO_CONSENTRATION_NUMBER);
                co_concentration.setText(v);
              }

       }

}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    stopService(new Intent(AlarmService.ALARM_SERVICE));
    getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(mMyReceiver);

}
```

}
What happens is that I get only one new string and then nothing.

Any help will be very usefull.

Comment: Do you mean no broadcast message is sent or received on MyReceiver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the class `ActivityCOConsentration`

you have to filter the broadcast Action as follow (call registerInetents() just after onCreate and remeber to unregister before destroy (`getApplicationcontext().unregisterReceiver(receiver);`)  :

```
private void registerIntents() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

    filter.addAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);

    getApplicationcontext().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

and use as receiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(AlarmService.BROADCAST_ACTION)) {

                String v = intent.getExtras().getString(CO_CONSENTRATION_NUMBER);
                co_concentration.setText(v);
             }
           }

}
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at this new problem. Thanks again for your time.